# Recording, streaming and recieving audio over a LAN with python

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, audio, streaming, pyaudio

I'm looking into coding a very simple LAN based home monitoring system using python 2.7 on Windows. I have a number of computers around the house each with a usb webcam attached.  The cameras have built in microphones.  I'm looking for the best way to capture and stream the audio and video over the network, then recieve and view/listen to it.  I'm guessing I'd have to use PyAudio to get the audio from the microphone and CV2 to get the video, past that, I'm not sure how I'd stream that data to another computer, recieve it and then view/listen to it.

Answer (score 0):

Not realy a question here, but still I guess I have a solution for you
(but there a millions of ways to solve this.)

My way is **[ROS](http://www.ros.org/) (Robot Operating System)**, which is basically a TCP/IP Service Wrapper. Anyway you can simple broadcast and receive streams via your network.
ROS can be implemented in C++ or **Python**.
ROS usually applies **OpenCV** as CV-library, so it should suite your wishes.

Straight forward **examples for video** are (i.e.) here:

- [mjpeg_server](http://wiki.ros.org/mjpeg_server)
- [web_video_server](http://wiki.ros.org/web_video_server)

**Audio streaming** is introduced here:

- [audio_common](http://wiki.ros.org/audio_common/Tutorials/Streaming%20audio) (there might be solutions via PyAudio. Not sure if other solutions might come more easy and still suitable.)